# Chosen-select on bootstrap modal was hiding after selecting a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
var config = {
      '.chosen-select'           : {},
      '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
      '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
      '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
      '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }

function add_course()
{
    $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
    $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
    $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
     $('#modal_form').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('.chosen-select', this).chosen('destroy').chosen();
     });  
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>



<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="add_course()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add Course</button>

<!-- Bootstrap modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Course Form</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body form">
        <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
          <input type="hidden" value="" name="train_ID" />
          <div class="form-body">
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
                Select Department:
                <select name="empdept[]" data-placeholder="Choose department..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
                  <option value="IT">IT</option>
                  <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
                  <option value="Production">Production</option>
                  <option value="HR">HR</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>           
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
<!-- End Bootstrap modal -->
```

Hi guys please help me to solve this.

I have a chosen select on a bootstrap modal it works fine 
but after I choose an item it disappear .

Heres my screenshot [when modal loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxhxF.png)

and heres what happened after I select [it disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuYaF.png)

Heres my code : 
 It is working here but on my website it doesn't work ..

Comment: can you create jsfiddle example of it?

Comment: please see code snippet that's what I want on my site but its not working  its hiding .

Comment: Can you give link of website in comment once it's resolved you can remove your comment.